# Location of the fonts on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, fonts, filesystems, freetype2

I'm using the FreeType2 library in an iPhone project, and I'm trying to simply load a TTF file from the system, if possible.

```
FT_Library  library;
FT_Face face;
int error;


error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );

if ( error == 0 )
     printf("Initialized FreeType2\r\n");   /* Prints */

error = FT_New_Face(library, "/System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica.ttf", 0, &face);

if ( error ==  FT_Err_Cannot_Open_Resource )
    printf("Font not found\r\n");         /* Prints */
```

That error seems to be for file not found.  Is /System/Library/Fonts  not the location of the fonts?  Or, do iPhone apps simply not have any read access at all to that directory.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, so everyone knows.  I did go ahead and add a .ttf into my project to see if it would load that, and yes, it did.  I'm just not sure if the system font is specified incorrectly, or if I don't have access to it.

Comment: I would like to use FreeType because of portability reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the fonts installed on your device, load the font manifest (a plist):

```
NSDictionary *cgFonts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/Fonts/CGFontCache.plist"];
```

Once you parse it, you'll find the entry for your font:

```
Helvetica = "/System/Library/Fonts/Cache/Helvetica.ttf";
```

Comment: http://modmyi.com/wiki/index.php/IPhone_Fonts
Not sure how accurate this page is, but it's what I had used as a reference.

Comment: You can always get the available fonts using the code listed in this article: http://excitabyte.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/the-font-family-names-available-on-iphone-os/

Answer (score 3):

They're either in `/System/Library/Fonts/` or `/System/Library/Fonts/Cache`. However, I suspect that you may not have the required permissions to access those directories.