# How to use freetype to render emoji character on iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl, emoji, freetype

FreeType supports emoji character since version 2.5. I want to render the emoji via FreeType and then use it in OpenGL, so no UIKit API would be used here. However, I don't want, neither I don't have the license, to ship an "Apple Color Emoji.ttf" file with my app.

So the question:
Is there any way to load the system emoji font file on the iOS device?
Is there any Objective-c or c/c++ API could access the system emoji font file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's clear up a misconception.  You don't have to use UIKit to render fonts using system libraries on iOS.  You can use Core Text (which has a regular old C interface) to render text directly into an offscreen buffer, and use that buffer as a texture with OpenGL.  This will automatically handle a *positively enormous* amount of work that you'd otherwise be doing yourself:

- Character encodings
- Text shaping
- Line breaking
- Kerning
- Glyph substitution
- Font selection (bold, italic, etc)
- Et cetera

Core Text is really a substitute for FreeType + HarfBuzz + Pango + ICU.  I would only use FreeType directly if I wanted to do something which Core Text can't do as easily, like render glyphs into an sprite sheet and use that to draw text, or if I wanted to share code across platforms.

Now, if you're convinced that it's worth the extra weeks to do it yourself, you'll have to parse the `/System/Library/Fonts/CGFontCache.plist` file to find the location of your desired font.  See: [Location of the fonts on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556874/location-of-the-fonts-on-the-iphone)

Comment: Great answer! Indeed I use FreeType because I need to arrange my glyphs into a sprite sheet. So in conclusion I should try the Core Text for the emoji and I could get the texture data which would be use in the OpenGL later.